# How can I launch any application using terminal?

Tags: 16.04, command-line

I tried to launch some packages with terminal. If I type `teamviewer` in terminal in launches but most of the application didn't.

Can anyone be able to help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Please Give us some examples of programs that you are not able to run using terminal...

Comment: The package you install may not be the name of the application but installs the application/s. For example the package `bridge-utils` contains a couple of programs you can execute but neither of those is called bridge-utils

Comment: I tried installing No machine and and other application like google chrome and and Libreoffice Writer it doesn't work. I couldn't able to find the right name for apllication to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening up the program you want normally, check task viewer for its process name, enter it in the terminal

You can also partially enter the process name, press tab, and the rest of it gets autocompleted (if there aren't any other programs named similarly)

`google-` then tab, and `google-chrome` should appear, then press enter (apologies if I remembered that command wrong. I can't actually check right now)

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, application names and package names can be different. For example LibreOffice can be started with the following:

```
soffice
```

And you can specify the exact program to launch by adding arguments:

```
soffice --writer
soffice --calc
```

There are also dedicated commands:

```
swriter
scalc
```

By the way these names come from the time, when LibreOffice was called StarOffice.

You have also mentioned Google Chrome, in that case, the application can be started with `google-chrome`.

By the way, when in doubt about the name of the command for a package, you might use the `apt-file` command as

```
apt-file list <package_name>
```

It will show all the files provided by the package. Though you need to install it first by `sudo apt install apt-file`.